# Filter returns everything But should only return some

Tags: javascript, filter

I am writing a function to limit search results from an array of objects. It seems to be working mostly... but still returns the unwanted objects.

Here is my code/explanation so far - Can you help me figure out why it still returns the unwanted objects?

I start by filtering my array, tourBands, to include only  bands that have certain event types. This works fine.

The second .filter() is where I am having issues. This is filtering the bands that are in town within 3 days before the selected performanceDate. The problem is even though the console.log() works at the end of the second .filter(), it still returns the band even when it shouldnt.

The code below has comments to explain whats going on.

```
    {
        bandTypes === "touring"
            ? tourBands
                .filter(band => {
                    if(showType !== 'Show Type'){
                        return band.showTypes.includes(showType)
                    }else {
                        return band
                    }
                })
                .filter(band => {
                    //User Clicks Button to Search within 3 days of the tourDate. This sets filterTourBandsByDate to true.

                    if(filterTourBandsByDate){

                        //Each Band may have more than 1 tour date.. so I now start filtering through all the tour dates. This Works.

                        band.bandTour.filter(tourDate => {

                            //Now I check to see if this tour date is within 100 miles of the savedLocation, which is their search location. This works.

                            let distanceToSearch = turf.distance(tourDate.geometry.coordinates, savedLocation, {units: 'miles'})    
                            if(distanceToSearch <= 100){

                                //If the specific tour location is within 100 miles of the saved location, I need to make sure that the tour location being filtered is actuall upcoming and not in the past.

                                let year = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(0,4)
                                let month = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(5, 7)
                                let day = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(8)

                                let tourDateFormatted = new Date(year, month - 1, day)

                                //Check to make sure the tour date is upcoming - This works.

                                if(new Date() < tourDateFormatted ){
                                    //Now I am going to change the tour date to 3 days before the actual tour date. Then i'll check to see if the performanceDate (The users entered date) is past the new date. 

                                    tourDateFormatted.setDate(tourDateFormatted.getDate() - 3);

                                    if(performanceDate > tourDateFormatted ){
                                        console.log(tourDate)

                                        //Returns Correct Tour Date in the correct location. If I select a date that shouldnt return the band, the console.log does NOT fire, but it still returns the band.
                                        return band
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })

                    }else{
                        return band
                    }
                })
                .reduce(
                    (allPosts, band) =>
                        allPosts.concat(
                            (band.youtube.length > 0 &&
                                band.bandBio !== "n/a" &&
                                band.bandGenre !== "n/a")
                                ? band.posts.map((post) => ({ post, band }))
                                : []
                        ),
                    []
                )
                .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.post.date) - new Date(a.post.date))
                .slice(0, page * 10)
                .map(({ post, band }) => convertPost(post, band))
            : null
    }
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in the `if(filterTourBandsByDate){` block.

Comment: Hmm I thought I was returning 'band' in the last if statement of that block?

Comment: You're returning that in the `band.bandTour.filter` callback, not in the if block. I think I see what you need now, working on answer.

Comment: I see! Yeah your right. there is no return. I tried `return band.bandTour.filter`

Comment: That'll always return an Array (truthy), so you're stuck with another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second `.filter` function, you're not always returning a value. You are doing a search operation with a `band.bandTour.filter(...)` call, but the value you return from that is not going to bubble out and be the result of the second filter function.

You should be able to replace that third nested filter with a loop. Alternately, you can replace that third `.filter(...)` call with a `.some(...)` (since you're trying to find if one value matches).

Loop version:

```
.filter(band => {
  if(filterTourBandsByDate){
    for (const tourDate of band.bandTour) {
      let distanceToSearch = turf.distance(tourDate.geometry.coordinates, savedLocation, {units: 'miles'})    
      if(distanceToSearch <= 100){
        let year = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(0,4)
        let month = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(5, 7)
        let day = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(8)

        let tourDateFormatted = new Date(year, month - 1, day)

        if(new Date() < tourDateFormatted ){
          tourDateFormatted.setDate(tourDateFormatted.getDate() - 3);
          return (performanceDate > tourDateFormatted);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return true
  }
})
```

Function chaining version:

```
.filter(band => !filterTourBandsByDate || band.bandTour.some(tourDate => {
  let distanceToSearch = turf.distance(tourDate.geometry.coordinates, savedLocation, {units: 'miles'})    
  if(distanceToSearch <= 100){
    let year = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(0,4)
    let month = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(5, 7)
    let day = tourDate.geometry.tourDate.slice(8)

    let tourDateFormatted = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
    if(new Date() < tourDateFormatted ){
      tourDateFormatted.setDate(tourDateFormatted.getDate() - 3);
      return performanceDate > tourDateFormatted;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow ok! I'll work on this and see what happens! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm. Is `return performanceDate > tourDateformatted;` at the end of the function chaining version going to return the whole band object? It still returns the whole band object even if the performanceDate is less than the tourDateFormatted.

Comment: `return performanceDate > tourDateFormatted;` does return true or false correctly but it still doesnt get rid of the band from the results if it returns false

Comment: It should. The `.filter(...)` function is supposed to return a boolean to control whether you keep (`true`) or discard (`false`) the value. You've been returning band objects in your filter function, but JavaScript just considers those "truthy" values.

Comment: Ahh. This is user error! Thanks for the help! It works!